# Laravel validation for accepting only predefined values from api

Tags: laravel, validation, default-value

Basically I wrote an api in laravel, The api should return a validation error if any of the key has wrong values (spelling mistakes,extra space). To make more clarity, in the web interface these key values are from select boxes . so users do not get to type anything.

First consider using `in_array` function for every inputs. I think that works. But i would like to know if there is anything for laravel specific.

something like

`'email' => 'required | email| 'sandy@stackoverflow.com`'

to make it ease.  I could not find it unfortunately. It seems not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this with `in`, for example:

```
$rule = [
    'email' => 'in:sandy@stackoverflow.com',
];
```

Or you could try it including the `Rule` namespace as described in the docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#rule-in)

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'zones' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['first-zone', 'second-zone']),
    ],
]);
```

Comment: i put in_array function for those specific inputs and had to return error if it fails for each of them.